# Maximum distance a particle can move

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics

This is problem 2.13 in Marion and Thornton's Classical Mechanics book. They ask to show that the maximum distance a particle can move under the influence of a retarding force equal to $mk(v^3+a^2v)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2ka}$ and that the particle only comes to rest at $t \rightarrow \infty$. If you've seen their solutions manual, their solution is relatively long and involves some tricky substitutions. So, I was wondering whether this problem can be solved alternatively in the following way:

Use the substitution $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = v\frac{dv}{dt}$ and integrate $\frac{dv}{v^2+a^2}=-kdx$. We'd then get $$x=\frac{1}{ka}\left[\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{v_i}{a}\right)-\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{v}{a}\right)\right]$$
We could then claim that $v \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ (which makes sense considering the problem), or we could integrate $\frac{v}{v(v^2+a^2)}=-kdt$ the same way they did and isolate $v$ in terms of $t$ just to confirm the claim. Thus, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, we have $x=\frac{1}{ka}\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{v_i}{a}\right)$, which is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2ka}$ for any initial velocity.

Would this be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's valid, except you'd want to point out that $x(t)$ is always increasing, which means it's absolute max will be as $t\to\infty$. I.e. make sure you didn't miss a potential absolute max anywhere on $t\geq0$.